# Flex movie delayed in inactive window

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I often want to run a movie but are only insterested in the debugging output and switch back to my code or to the debugger.

I discovered, that the movie framerate is significantly slower in an inactive browser window. This causes e.g. certain async unit tests to fail when run in the Flex UI. So it's not that trivial.

Does anyone know what happens here?

My setup: IE, Debugging player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was introduced since Flash Player 10.1. You can read more details [here](http://www.kaourantin.net/2010/03/timing-it-right.html).

Comment: Thanks, could not set up reasonable search terms to find anything here.